# How to set jqGrid width responsive with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

How to set jqGrid width equal to '100%' in bootstrap framework?

I have tried

```
autowidth: true, 
width: '100%', 
shrinkToFit: false,
```

but it is not working. 
I've also tried putting '%' to all the columns, but turned out an ugly table.

Answer (score 0):

Below, list is your jqgrid id and pager is pager id of jqgrid

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {
    $('.ui-jqdialog').center();
    $("#list").setGridWidth($('#gridDiv').width(), true);
    $("#pager").setGridWidth($('#gridDiv').width(), true);
});
```